# Consulta SQL na tabela wp_postmeta

Tags: sql

Como faço uma consulta SQL em uma tabela que tem o seguintes campos:

```
SELECT meta_key,meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'cidade' and meta_key = 'bairro'
```

os campos da tabela wp_postmeta campo meta_key = 'Cidade' e meta_value = 'Curitiba' e meta_key = 'bairro' e meta_value = 'Centro' é o seguinte quero fazer um select quando eu selecionar uma cidade no outro select ele mostre só os bairros relacionadas a cidade que foi selecionada então quero saber se tem como fazer isso, se tem como faço esse relacionamento no sql?

Comment: Postes mais informações sobre o problema, não está claro o que você quer e o que você não sabe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua consulta parece estar correta, mas fique atento ao nome da base. No Wordpress (que eu assumo que você está usando), o nome da tabela é `wp_postmeta` e não `wp_postpostmeta`.

Em um caso mais abrangente, um simples `select meta_key, meta_value from wp_postmeta` retorna todas as ocorrências dos dois campos

**EDIT**

A sua consulta não está tão correta assim, pelo menos pra mim. Você está procurando todas as cidades E todos os bairros, ou todos os bairros de uma cidade? Na lógica do WordPress, `meta_key` determina o nome do campo, enquanto `meta_value`, o seu valor. Portanto, você teria `meta_key = 'Cidade'` e `meta_value = 'Curitiba'`, por exemplo. **NESTE CASO** (i.e., se a sua lógica é essa), pra selecionar todas as cidades da sua relação, sua consulta seria:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='Cidade'
```

Assim, você receberia retornos do tipo

```
meta_key | meta_value 
Cidade   | Curitiba
Cidade   | São Paulo
```

Se, em contra partida, a sua `meta_key` seja o **NOME** da cidade, e a `meta_value` o **NOME** do bairro, a consulta

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='São Paulo'
```

Poderia retornar:

```
meta_key  | meta_value 
São Paulo | Morumbi
São Paulo | Jabaquara
```

Se esta última lógica que eu representei for a que você está seguindo (i.e., `meta_key = 'nome_da_cidade'`), e você quer listar todos os bairros de todas cidades (novamente, estou assumindo coisas aqui), faça:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta ORDER BY meta_key
```

Tirei minhas conclusões baseando-me na sua pergunta. Veja se estou correto e me avise

Comment: Você está certo estou realizando a consulta com nome correto da tabela wp_postmeta, campo meta_key = 'Cidade' e meta_value = 'Curitiba' e meta_key = 'bairro' e meta_value = 'Centro' é o seguinte quero fazer um select quando eu selecionar uma cidade no outro select ele mostre só os bairros relacionadas a cidade que foi selecionada então quero saber se tem como fazer isso, se tem como  faço esse relacionamento no sql?

Comment: Saulo, se você tem os pares `meta_key = 'Cidade' , meta_value = 'Curitiba'`, e `meta_key = 'bairro' , meta_value = 'centro'`, eles se tornam independentes, sem relação entre si. Na minha opinião, você teria que ter a `meta_key` do segundo par como o nome da cidade, e não como  bairro (i.e., `meta_key =  'São Paulo'`), aí o `meta_value` será o nome do bairro e aí sim você consegue relacionar os bairros com as cidade

Comment: Antedi valeu pela dica vou testar, muito obrigado!

Comment: Veja o exemplo que eu dei na minha resposta. Imagine que `meta_key` é outro nome para cidade, e `meta_value` é outro nome para bairro. Assim o seu relacionamento fica mais simples.

Comment: Valeu pelas dicas, eu resolvi o problema criando uma taxonomia customizada para adicionar as cidades. Valeu a todos

Comment: Não esqueça de validar as respostas que você achou  que lhe ajudaram

Comment: Tenho que ter 15 pontos de reputação, ainda não tenho!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT meta_key,meta_value FROM wp_postpostmeta WHERE meta_key = 'cidade' OR meta_key = 'bairro'
```

Comment: Eu me atentei apenas a query, no caso do nome de tabelas do WP faça o que o Caio Felipe disse.

Answer (score 0):

O problema na sua consulta é que está utilizando o `and` entre as duas condições.
Dessa forma, o banco vai entender que ele deve retornar os campos `meta_key` e `meta_value` de todas as linhas que contenham a `meta_key` no valor de 'cidade' e de 'bairro', mas não tem como a `meta_key` conter dois valores diferentes na mesma linha.

Para corrigir, você deve utilizar o operador `or`, visto que na sua lógica você quer que o banco retorne as colunas dos registros que tenham a `meta_key` no valor de 'cidade' OU de 'bairro'.

```
SELECT meta_key,meta_value from wp_postpostmeta where (meta_key = 'cidade' OR meta_key = 'bairro')
```

Comment: É o seguinte quero fazer um select quando eu selecionar uma cidade  no outro select ele mostre só os bairros relacionadas a cidade que foi selecionada então quero saber como faço esse relacionamento no sql?

Comment: Simples, você preciso identificar nos registros referentes ao bairro, qual coluna é a coluna que apresenta a cidade. E então filtrar o select por lá. Logo mais eu altero a minha resposta e te mostro como fazer ok?

Comment: @Saulo Para que eu consiga editar a resposta, preciso que você coloque na resposta todas as colunas e seus valores de uma linha referente ao bairro, pois com certeza existe alguma coluna que faz o relacionamento entre o bairro e a cidade, e essa coluna não é nenhuma das que você especificou.

Comment: Só que já dei uma verificada nas tabelas para saber qual o campo vou usar para fazer essa filtragem mas até momento não encontrei, se no meu post = Casa01 na categoria = venda cidade = São Paulo bairro = Morumbi, e em outro post = casa02 categoria = locar cidade = São Paulo, bairro = Centro,  qual o campo vou usar para fazer o relacionamento?